# JDBC insert real array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jdbc

I am attempting to insert a real array into a postgresql array:

the table definition is:

```
String sqlTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ccmBlock"
                + "   sampleId             INTEGER,"
                + "   block                REAL[])";
```

The insert is:

```
String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO ccmBlock"
                 + "(sampleId, block) VALUES" 
                 + "(?,?)"; 
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = theConnection.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);

preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1); 

Object[] theArray = {.11f, .22f, .33f};
Array a = theConnection.createArrayOf("real", theArray);  
preparedStatement.setArray(2, a);
```

I get a message:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unable to find server array type for provided name real.

but on their documentation page:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-numeric.html

Table 8-2. Numeric Types

Name  StorageSize Description                 Range

**real**  4 bytes     variable-precision, inexact 6 decimal digits precision

Comment: Java "floating points" literals are of type `double`, so 8 byte. Have you tried `{.11f, .22f, .33f}` for your array?

Comment: The message is complaining that it can't find a real type for the server, not that the format of the array is wrong.  I tried your suggestion and the result is the same.  When I first tried this part of the application I used floats and I got lazy when I was trying to make it work.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I missed that. However, the type `"real"` isn't known to the postgresql jdbc driver, apparently it's called [float4](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/postgresql/postgresql/9.0-801.jdbc4/org/postgresql/jdbc2/TypeInfoCache.java#TypeInfoCache.0types)

Comment: That is correct, I googled everything I could think of, where did you find that?  Especially when it creates the table correctly.

Answer (score 7):

The Postgresql JDBC driver has it's own idea about the naming of types. You can look them up in the [TypeInfoCache class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901.jdbc4/org/postgresql/jdbc2/TypeInfoCache.java/).

In your case, the correct name is `float4`, so the line would go:

```
Object[] theArray = {.11f, .22f, .33f};
Array a = theConnection.createArrayOf("float4", theArray);
```

Props goes to @JBNizet for suggesting this registry in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7931654/785663).

Comment: using `namedParameterJdbcTemplate..getJdbcOperations().execute((ConnectionCallback<Array>) con -> con.createArrayOf("float4", arr));` I still get `Unable to find server array type for provided name REAL.` - `org.postgres:postgresql:42.2.19`