# Insert cube into postgres database using spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I had a repository like so:

```java
@Repository
interface Repository {
    @Query("insert into t values (cube(:array))")
    void save(float[] array)
}
```

which gives there error `Unable to find server array type for provided name REAL.`

I even tried to manually build a query string of the form: `insert into t values (cube(array[0.1,0.3,0.2,...]::float4[]))` and also `insert into t values (cube('{0.1,0.3,0.2,...}'::float4[]))` but I get the same error.

I added the `float4[]` cast as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813300/jdbc-insert-real-array) the user seems to solve the error by using a `float4` array instead of `real` array.

I also tried to use the `Connection.createArrayOf("float4", ...)` but when I try to auto-wire the `Connection` I get this error on startup:

> required a bean of type 'java.sql.Connection' that could not be found.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve? All examples of `CUBE` with Postgres use it in a `GROUP BY` clause where it takes a list of column names as arguments. I'm not sure what the purpose would be in an insert statements with an array of numbers as an argument.

Comment: @JensSchauder I'm storing a vector in my table.

Comment: @JensSchauder The problem is the library is mapping `float[]` to `real[]`, which is broken.I had to manually map my `float[]` to a `java.sql.Array` with `type="float4"`

Comment: which involved the use of a `JdbcTemplate`