# java.sql.Connection createArrayOf() always returns null

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to insert a series of values into a sql query using Java's postgresql jdbc4.

`java.sql.Connection` specifies a method to convert `Object[]` into `java.sql.Array`: `conn.createArrayOf(String typeName, Object[] elements)`

The only problem is, no matter what I try, it always returns null.

```
public Array makeQueryBigintArray(Object[] values) throws SQLException {
    Array result = conn.createArrayOf("bigint", values);
    // "result" is null at this point, but shouldn't be
    return result;
}
```

`conn` is retrieved through a working `javax.sql.DataSource` via `dataSource.getConnection()`. `conn` works for all our other database uses, but its `createArrayOf()` method always returns null.

I have tried both upper case "BIGINT" and lower case "bigint" for typeName, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931654/how-create-a-sql-array-from-a-java-list), to no avail.

When I dig through the debugger, I find that `conn` is a `org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection` wrapping a `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection`.

If the feature wasn't supported by postgres/JDBC4, I would expect calling it to throw a SQLException indicating it's unsupported. No exception is thrown.

Any clue as to *why* it's returning null?

How can I fix it, or else, how can I pass in an array or List of values to a `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: Are you using a recent JDBC 4(!) driver of PostgreSQL? It looks like it is implemented: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/org/postgresql/jdbc4/AbstractJdbc4Connection.java#L88 (and has been for a few years now)

Comment: Could you try with `"int8"`? `"bigint"` is just an alias of `"int8"` (but both should be used in this context).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel We're using a build that is only 2 builds behind the most current PostgreSQL JDBC. That is, we are using build 1002, and build 1004 is the most current as of 12/19/14. I had similar thoughts that maybe it was a really old one, but it's recent.

Comment: Ok, but are you using the jdbc 4 build? Afaik, the jdbc 3 build doesn't have it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah, JDBC 4 standard, build 1002.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you found some way to fix it?

Comment: @RockyMM Sadly, no, I have not found a solution. Which means our code still inserts a csv string into the SQL string, instead of using parameters in a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Tomcat6 installed using some Linux packaging system, then you probably have old versions of commons-jdbc and commons-dbcp in its `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib` directory. These old commons-jdbc and commons-dbcp libraries apparently have some bug when creating SQL arrays.

Apache team decided to stop maintaining commons-dbcp and moved on to tomcat-dbcp, due to code complexity and various perceived drawbacks.

What I did was I went to Maven Central, downloaded latest [tomcat-jdbc](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.tomcat%7Ctomcat-jdbc%7C8.0.23%7Cjar) and [tomcat-dbcp](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.tomcat%7Ctomcat-dbcp%7C8.0.23%7Cjar) and put those into `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib` and moved commons-jdbc and commons-dbcp JARs into `/tmp`. I also had to add to context file located in `/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/my_app.xml` following

```
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
```

What I think is happening is that there is a bug in handling exceptions in some of the JDBCConnection wrappers, which there are many many in commons-dbcp. There is part of the code which I suspect is [the culprit](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/DelegatingConnection.java#DelegatingConnection.createArrayOf%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) but I'm not sure why and how. All in all, as soon as I moved from commons-dbcp, things started working again.

Comment: What on Earth does this answer have to do with the question?

Comment: Let me quote myself: "As soon as I moved from commons-dbcp, things started working again" I have described to you what had worked for me. Do you have Tomcat 6 installed?

Comment: I have Tomcat 7.0.25.

Comment: Do try with latest tomcat-dbcp. Here is another suggestion that the problem is there: http://postgresql.nabble.com/Error-when-attempting-to-call-Connection-createArrayOf-method-td2170993.html

Comment: @MartinCarney Any luck with changing the connection pool?